# Show custom view over VideoView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-videoview

I am trying to show a custom view on top of a VideoView both should be full screen, with the custom layout showing on top of the VideoView, but at the moment my custom view shows on the left of the screen and the VideoView on the right.

[This is what I am trying to achieve. Show a custom layout(full screen) on top of the video(also full screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEh0G.jpg)

But at the moment, this is how it's shown:
[Custom view on the left and Video to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK4Cj.jpg)

How can I make my custom view to show on top of the VideoView?

These are my xml layouts and Custom View:

**activity_fullscreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

    <com.buffup.sdk.ui.BuffView
        android:id="@+id/buff_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </com.buffup.sdk.ui.BuffView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/buff_question"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**buff_question.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dark_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:padding="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/test_color_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Where do you think Jorge \n will put this penalty? I'd\n go left here! " />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/question_time_progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:indeterminateDuration="1"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_time"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/test_color_light"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="14" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**BuffView.kt**

```
class BuffView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.test, this)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't find `test.xml` in `activity_fullscreen.xml`.

Comment: test.xml is the custom view <com.buffup.sdk.ui.BuffView> the layout is inflated in the BuffView.kt class

Comment: I don't think you should do like this. Why didn't you take ``<include layout="@layout/buff_question"/>` into your `activity_fullscreen` with your `VideoView` so that `FrameLayout` will have 2 views inside it.

Comment: the @layout/buff_question should be part of an external sdk that builds a custom view to show on top of the video. These are the requirements: We want an SDK that the Provided Android App Uses to display content over the existing video.

The SDK should expose a view that the host Application is adding over the video frame that displays the content there.

The SDK should have the following features:

Expose a view that the host App will add in the UI over the video stream to display the content
Handle all the business and UI logic to display the content over the video in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you take `VideoView` out of `BuffView` like this and try ?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">

<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

  <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
  <com.buffup.sdk.ui.BuffView
    android:id="@+id/buff_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Yay! That was it! I think I tried the other way around, first the BuffView and then the VideoView so the video was covering the BuffView. Thank you so much! :)